# Replacing multiple occurrence by single occurrence in string

Tags: sql, regex, hana

I have data like "11223311" and I want all the multiple occurrence to be replaced by single occurrence i.e. the above should turn into '123'. I am working in SAP HANA.

But by using below logic I am getting 
'1231' from '11223311'.

```
SELECT  REPLACE_REGEXPR('(.)\1+' IN '11223331' WITH '\1' OCCURRENCE ALL)  FROM DUMMY;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression only replaces multiple **consecutive** occurrences of characters; that's what the `\1+` directly after it's matching `(.)` is doing.

You can use look-ahead to remove all characters that also occur somewhere after that match. Note that this keeps the *last* occurrence, not the first:

```
SELECT  REPLACE_REGEXPR('(.)(?=.*\1)' IN '11223331' WITH '' OCCURRENCE ALL)  FROM DUMMY
```

This returns: `231`

If you want to keep the *first* occurrence, I don't see a possibility just with one regex (I could be wrong though). Using a look-behind in the same way does not work because it would need to be variable-length, which is not supported in HANA and most other implementations. Often \K is recommended as alternative, but something like `(.).*\K\1` wouldn't work with replace all, because all characters before \K are still consumed in replace. If you could run the same regex in a loop, it could work but then why not use a non-regex loop (like a user-defined HANA function) in the first place.

Comment: I loved this solution

Comment: @hannobo It really worked well, thanks a lott :)
 Can you tell me how"(.)(?=.*\1)" works??

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava: Written in text it would be "Match one character `(.)` that is followed by any number of any characters `.*`, followed by the first character again `\1`." The `(?=  )` is a look-ahead ensuring that the condition is met but the matching characters are not consumed, so replace can go through character by character.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT  REPLACE_REGEXPR(concat(concat('[^','11223331'),']') IN '0123456789' WITH '' OCCURRENCE ALL)  
FROM    DUMMY;
```

Comment: concat() expects exactly two parameters; this one gives "SAP DBTech JDBC: [316]: wrong number of arguments in function invocation". Why not just write `'[^11223331]'`?

Comment: @Hannobo - The real use-case is obviously not the hard-coded value 11223331. Code fixed. Thanks